# Executar um áudio com Angular 13

Tags: angular, funções

Estou tentando executar um áudio ao clicar em um botão com Angular 13, esse botão está na minha página principal no arquivo app.component.html padrão do angular.

```
<html>
  <button class="card wrapper" (click)="playSound()">Play a Sound</button>
</html
```

A função playSound() que está sendo executada no botão está no meu app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  playSound() {
    console.log("cliquei")
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "../music.mp3";
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

A função é chamada corretamente, o console log da primeira linha dessa função aparece a cada clique que eu dou no botão, mas a música não é executada.
O caminho do arquivo está correto, estou na pasta app dentro de src e a música está solta na pasta src.

Log do console:

```
cliquei
GET http://localhost:4200/music.mp3 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
Blocked autofocusing on a <input> element in a cross-origin subframe.
```

Ao tentar retirar a responsabilidade da função a encontrar o local do áudio, removi a seguinte linha:

`audio.src = "../music.mp3";`

E coloquei o atributo src direto na tag HTML do botão, modificando a tag para que fique assim:

`<button class="card wrapper" src="../music.mp3" (click)="playSound()">Play a Sound</button>`

Dessa forma o console não registrou mais nenhum erro, mas a música continua não sendo reproduzida.

Comment: Talvez o problema esteja na tag `audio`, já tentou colocar o **src** direto na tag?

Comment: Eu comentei a linha "audio.src = "../music.mp3";" que está na função e coloquei o src direto no button  da seguinte forma: src="../music.mp3" e isso removeu o seguinte erro do console 
"GET http://localhost:4200/music.mp3 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
chrome-error://chromewebdata/:2452 Blocked autofocusing on a <input> element in a cross-origin subframe."

Mas ainda não reproduziu o audio.

Comment: 404 not found significa que o arquivo mp3 não está localizado nesse endereço que você especificou

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento editei a pergunta explicando de forma mais clara o que ocorre no console, quando adiciono o src na tag ele reconhece normalmente o local do audio, não retornando erro 404.

Comment: Com o código atual não conseguimos reproduzir o problema, é importante **[edit] e adicionar um [mcve] (NÃO delete e NÃO repita a pergunta)**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva e então aguarde o processo de reabertura (que será avaliado por outros usuários). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.